# Unable to Find Database Location and Plist Location In ios Simulator in Xcode 4.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode

i am Unable to Find Database Location and Plist Location In ios Simulator in Xcode 4.3.2..

I installed xcode 4.3.2 but unable to find ios simulator5.1 in  "/library/application support / ios simulator"

in application support i am unable to see ios simulator ....

i use plist i insert some entry n fetch the data the code works perfectly but where is the plist file in which the data is store in simultor?

This is plist path

/Users/utkarshsingh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/ADA62A25-A47A-4DCA-AE1C-596F2CF79446/Documents/Login.plist

This is my database path

/Users/utkarshsingh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/620BA7E6-4B1A-4439-B94C-58C0F088DD83/Documents

how to find ios simulator in application support or in xcode 4.3.2 the ios simulator 5.1 somewhere else?

Plz help me to find ios simlator in application support...

Thank You....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My simulator is under

> /Users/MyUsername/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator

So you plist path

> /Users/utkarshsingh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/ADA62A25-A47A-4DCA-AE1C-596F2CF79446/Documents/Login.plist

And your database path

> /Users/utkarshsingh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/620BA7E6-4B1A-4439-B94C-58C0F088DD83/Documents

are valid.

If you can't see

> /Users/utkarshsingh/Library/

in you Finder press CMD+G and enter the path by hand.